# How to write the Python result to synapse azure database?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I am trying to write the result obtained using the pyspark in the notebook as a table to the database using the following code:

```
%%pyspark
sample=sample.head()

%%spark
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true")
park_df = spark.createDataFrame(sample)
park_df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("default.sample")
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error : <console>:31: error: not found: value park_df
val $ires9 = park_df
             ^
<console>:29: error: not found: value park_df
       park_df = spark.createDataFrame(sample)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to below to code to write the python result to synapse azure database:

```
%%pyspark
sample = [('CA',22,45000),('WA',35,65000)]
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true")
park_df = spark.createDataFrame(sample, ['state','age','salary'])
park_df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("default.sample")
```

[image]

Comment: Getting this error: ValueError : Some of types cannot be determined after inferring

Comment: The code you provided is working fine.. but when i running using my data frame,it is throwing the above error i mention. Is there any specific datatype issue while loading which in need to take care

Comment: @YogeshGovindan When you run `%%pyspark
sample=sample.head()`, you will receive this error message because 'sample' is not defined. I would suggest you to define the sample first and then run the below command.

Comment: when i removed NA from the dateset, then it is able to load into the default database. I could not understand how it happen. Is there a way to keep a check into the datasets because every column will have different datatype and imputing the NA to zero or removing is not a good idea.